# Snap pixel over-recording purchases on Shopify

Tags: shopify, pixel, facebook-pixel, snapchat

My Snap pixel is over-recording purchases whilst other events are also recording incorrect numbers. I'm confident this is due to errors whilst installing the pixel, especially as our website has changed since then.

Does anyone know how I could fix that please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try uninstalling the app using the app uninstall function (not just removing the app from the apps pages), each app comes with an uninstall function.

If this does not solves your issue, check the Additional scripts sections inside Settings -> checkout. make sure you don't have any pixel code there.

Comment: Hi Juandres, Thanks so much for your reply. The pixel isn't recording in the checkout page, do you know how I could fix that? In addition, how can I make sure the pixel is now working?

Comment: Something i faced on the past was that:

Shopify has an internal service to handle analytics scripts, that is called **Trekki**.

Trekki is injected inside **{{ content_for_header }}** make sure you only have one in both the theme.liquid and checkout.liquid (checkout only if you are in a shopify plus plan)